# How to determine block module given block delta

Tags: 7, views, blocks

Is there a way to determine a block's module given only the block's delta? I'm hoping for a solution that does not require a custom query.

**Use case:**
We are enabling our client to decide which blocks are displayed on a given content type. Those options include blocks created through the block admin interface and blocks created through the views admin. From what I can tell, a regular block and a view's block are rendered differently so psuedo code would be something like.

```
// In preprocessing
if($block_module === 'views') {
    // do view rendering
} else {
    // do normal block rendering
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer but might be useful depending on your use case: have you considered [Entity Views Attachments (EVA)](http://drupal.org/project/eva)?

Comment: Are you trying to theme a block differently depending on what module created it? If so, you can use the template system to achieve that. (E.g. `block--[module-1].tpl.php` and `block--[module-2].tpl.php`)

Comment: also you can handle it in theme level, for example `block--views.tpl.php` and `block.tpl.php` can render differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible without having the module name.

Block deltas only need to be unique *per module*, so any two modules could implement a block with exactly the same delta, and you'd have no way to determine which was which without the module name.

The simplest proof of this in the code is the [`block_load()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.module/function/block_load/7) function, which has this signature:

```
function block_load($module, $delta) {
```

As you can see, even Drupal can't load the details of a block without knowing the module name unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks Clive. In the end I did the following, which works well in my situation. Essentially, get a list of the blocks in the views module `$blocks = module_invoke('views', 'block_info');` and iterate through those to see if the delta exists. If it does, I know I have a views block, if not I know it's a regular block.